# I don't know how to bring certain data from firebase, Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am beginner in firebase and angular so I am learning by making a website, so I have made most of the website but I faced a problem I couldn't fix it, since last two weeks. The problem is I can't bring the certain data from firebase, for example I want to bring only the data that related to the country Morocco, but all them getting pulled. I want only when I click to Morocco flag shows only things related to the country Morocco. [Countries in the Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IveTn.png) [The published Article that related to the countries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FMrL.png) [the countries in the Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKPH6.png) [the publishes in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psOjR.png)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { cardItems } from '../../services/cardItems';
import { PublishedService } from '../../services/published.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-published-pages',
  templateUrl: './published-pages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./published-pages.component.css'],
})
export class PublishedPagesComponent implements OnInit {
  countries: Partial<cardItems>[] = [];

  filteredCountires: any[] = [];
  subscription: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(private publishService: PublishedService) {
    this.subscription = this.publishService.getAll().subscribe((actions) => {
      this.countries = [];

      actions.forEach((action) => {
        const val: any = action.payload.val();
        this.countries.push({
          $key: action.key ? action.key : '',
          ...(<Object>action.payload.val()),
        });
      });

      this.filteredCountires = this.countries;
    });
  }
  filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredCountires = query
      ? this.countries?.filter((p) =>
          p && p.category
            ? p.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
            : null
        )
      : this.countries;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

```css
THE SERVICE 

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { cardItems } from './cardItems';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PublishedService {
  countries: Partial<cardItems>[] = [];
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/publishes').snapshotChanges();
  }

  get(country: string) {
    return this.db.object('/publishes/' + country).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<p>
  <input
    #query
    (keyup)="filter(query.value)"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Search..."
  />
</p>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of filteredCountires">
      <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Firebase is a document-based database, you can not write SQL-like queries. When you request, you get the whole document and then you have to find you object using fiter or map function.

Comment: Any references could help me to do that ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-8_1

Here is the link, that you can filter the data, see if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. The following query returns Morocco country. The code is written using the Web version8.

```
 get(country: string) {
    var countryRef = this.db.collection("publishes");
    return countryRef.where("country", "==", "Morocco");
  }
```

Instead of "country", match your collection column name.

Here is the reference link, if you want to know more https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-8_1

Comment: it shows "Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'AngularFireDatabase'.ts(2339)"